# Remotely running pygame script from Django

Tags: python, django

On my Pi3 running Raspian, Apache server I have a Django App.

I'm trying to run a python file from Django.
If I SSH into my Pi and type "python test_data.py", it runs fine.  I SSH in as user "pi"

test_data.py is just this.

```
output = "success!"
print(output)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^mygame/$', views.my_game),
```

**views.py** file I have the following

```
from subprocess import PIPE, run

def my_game(request):
    command = ['sudo', 'python test_data.py']
    result = run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    return render(request, 'rungame.html',{'data1':result})
```

When /mygame is called via the web browser, here is the result I get printed in rungame.html, so I know it calls test_data.py.  It appears to be a permissions issue?  I don't understand what the following means.  Can someone advise if this is a permissions issue and how do I fix it?

```
CompletedProcess(args=['sudo', 'python mygame.py'], returncode=1, stdout='', stderr='usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V\
nusage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]\
nusage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]\n [command]\
nusage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p\n prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]\
nusage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p\n prompt] [-u user] file ...\n')
```

Thank you

ADDED INFO:
mygame.py created to test the concept

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
background = pygame.image.load('background1.png')


print("test")
game_over = False

while not game_over:
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

HERE IS MY APACHE CONF FILE

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    Alias /static /home/pi/Dev/ehome/src/static
        <Directory /home/pi/Dev/ehome/src/static>
           Require all granted
         </Directory>

    <Directory /home/pi/Dev/ehome/src/ehome>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess ehome python-path=/home/pi/Dev/ehome/src:/home/pi/Dev/ehome/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup ehome
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/Dev/ehome/src/ehome/wsgi.py


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: the user `pie` needs to have permission to execute the python script. You are trying to execute the `django` application through `apache` right?

Comment: yes, I'm using django on apache.

Comment: when I run ls -l it shows Pi has permission on mygame.py however root is the owner of mygame.pyc

Comment: you also have to make `apache`'s user (`www:data`) as the `group owner` and give it permission to execute the `wsgi.py` inside your application. I think you need to use something like `modwsgi` as well.  For more info you may look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: I'm struggling to get this, I have been reading for hours trying to find an answer.  My Django app works, I can log in a user, read the database, navigate several different pages.  So with that said, isn't apache's www-data user already using the wsgi.py file?

Comment: i added my apache settings, does the WSGIProcessGroup ehome need to be changed to pi or www-data?

Comment: you can work by adding wwe-data as a group owner. The whole process is going to be run by Apache now. It also needs permission to execute that directory.

Comment: I've gotten this to work with a simple script and it will return a variable back to the html page.  The issue appears to be caused by a pygame function "pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))"  the pygame code works when called via terminal/ssh and using sudo python mygame.py, it errors on the function above if you just use python mygame.py.  I've tried " os.system("sudo python mygame.py")" and it won't work when ran from views.py.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use subprocess to call the script. You have a python script, make it a function and import it in Django. Then call the function in your views.py.

**test_data.py**

```py
def my_function():
    output = "success!"
    return output
```

**views.py**

```
from test_data import my_function

def my_game(request):
    result = my_function()
    return render(request, 'rungame.html',{'data1':result})
```

Have the **test_data.py** script in the same directory with **views.py**.

Comment: I understand what you're saying regarding a function.  I created the test_data to figure out how to call another script.  I need to be able to just call/run the test_data.py (and not just a function) because my ultimate goal is to use Django as menu system for several pygame apps.  I have a mygame.py that opens a pygame window.  In testing I can call "sudo python mygame.py" via SSH and the window opens on the screen connected to the Pi.  I just can't get the same functionality from Django and it appears to be a permissions issue that I just don't understand. mygame.py code added above

Comment: I suggest you rename your question (+ title) to reflect what you are trying to achieve, as the original does not make sense. Make sure you mention execution of `pygame` script via Django.

Comment: My experience with `pygame` is limited, but it doesn't act as typical python module which you import. It is best somebody with `pygame` experience could advise you on best ways forward, but you need to correctly word your questions to get the help you need.

Comment: I don't think its related to pygame.  this is why i created the little test_data to see if I was getting the same error or if it was caused the the set_mode or other function of pygame..